# Adding a subchild to existing XML file with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've been bussy adding information to a existing XML file. first I searched for a specific inner text in the document and after it need to add more data (i.e. measuring points). In a previous thread regarding how to search I got some help on adding extra but to avoid the discussion goes off topic I open a new thread. An example of a XML file is shown below:

```
 <Root>
    <CompanyProfile>
        <CompanyName>ABB</CompanyName>
        <SiteName>GH WEG</SiteName>
        <ClientNumber />
        <Imo>123456</Imo>
        <MachineTotal>3</MachineTotal>
    </CompanyProfile>
    <MachineProfile>
        <MachineName>Mach1</MachineName>
        <SerialNumber>123456</SerialNumber>
        <TypeNumber>123</TypeNumber>
        <Type>123654</Type>
        <NominalSpeed>3000</NominalSpeed>
        <Frequency>50</Frequency>
        <NominalPower>1700</NominalPower>
    </MachineProfile>
    <MachineProfile>
        <MachineName>Mach2</MachineName>
        <SerialNumber>654987</SerialNumber>
        <TypeNumber>321</TypeNumber>
        <Type>987654</Type>
        <NominalSpeed>1500</NominalSpeed>
        <Frequency>50</Frequency>
        <NominalPower>1700</NominalPower>
    </MachineProfile>
</Root>
```

A combobox shows all the available machines and the datagridview has measurements that comes from a device. The main issue is that I want data to be added at the node in the XML file based on the selection in the combobox.

[image]

I'm able to search for a certain name in the document but when I add something it overrides all previous information and only add the new information.

This is the code I wrote:

```
private void btnStoreSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SelectedMachine = cmbMachineName.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int DE;
    int NDE;
    string MeasurePointHde;
    string MeasurePointVde;
    string MeasurePointAde;
    string MeasurePointHnde;
    string MeasurePointVnde;
    string MeasurePointAnde;
    string MeasurePoint;
    int TotalMeasurements = frmMain.MeasTotal;

    XmlMachineMeasurement NewMachineMeasurement = new XmlMachineMeasurement();

    //Create file and Load it
    XDocument ClientFile = XDocument.Load(frmMain.ClientFileName);

    //Search for element
    XElement machine = ClientFile.Root.Elements("MachineProfile").Where(x => (string)x.Element("MachineName") == SelectedMachine).FirstOrDefault();

    //Get recording numbers: E.G. two total machines than DE recording for Mach2 = (2 * 2) - 1 = 3 
    // and for NDE it is 2 * 2 = 4 
    DE = (int.Parse(cmbMeasurement.SelectedItem.ToString()) * 2) - 1;
    NDE = (int.Parse(cmbMeasurement.SelectedItem.ToString()) * 2);

    //Store the speed at which the measurement was taken
    NewMachineMeasurement.Speed=txbSpeed.Text;

    //Create string for searing for the right Measurements
    MeasurePointHde = "H" + DE.ToString();
    MeasurePointVde = "V" + DE.ToString();  
    MeasurePointAde = "A" + DE.ToString();
    MeasurePointHnde = "H" + NDE.ToString();
    MeasurePointVnde = "V" + NDE.ToString();    
    MeasurePointAnde = "A" + NDE.ToString();

    //Check for measuringpoint and add to class
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalMeasurements; i++)
    {
        MeasurePoint = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        switch (MeasurePoint)
        {
            case var value when value == MeasurePointHde:

                NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                NewMachineMeasurement.RMShorDE = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                break;

            case var value when value == MeasurePointVde:
                NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                NewMachineMeasurement.RMSvertDE = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                break;

            case var value when value == MeasurePointAde:
                NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                NewMachineMeasurement.RMSaxDE = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                break;

            case var value when value == MeasurePointHnde:
                NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                NewMachineMeasurement.RMShorNDE = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                break;

            case var value when value == MeasurePointVnde:
                NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                NewMachineMeasurement.RMSvertNDE = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                break;

            case var value when value == MeasurePointAnde:
                NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                NewMachineMeasurement.RMSaxNDE = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }

    //add machine measurements to XML file
    _root.MachineMeasurements.Add(new XmlMachineMeasurement()
    {
        MeasurementDate = NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate,
        Speed = NewMachineMeasurement.Speed,
        RMShorNDE = NewMachineMeasurement.RMShorNDE,
        RMSvertNDE = NewMachineMeasurement.RMSvertNDE,
        RMSaxNDE = NewMachineMeasurement.RMSaxNDE,
        RMShorDE = NewMachineMeasurement.RMShorDE,
        RMSvertDE = NewMachineMeasurement.RMSvertDE,
        RMSaxDE = NewMachineMeasurement.RMSaxDE,
    });

    HelperXml.SerializeObjectToXMLFile(_root, frmMain.ClientFileName);

    //Add the selected recording points
    /*machine.Add(new XElement("MeasurementDate", NewMachineMeasurement.MeasurementDate));
    machine.Add(new XElement("Speed", NewMachineMeasurement.Speed));
    machine.Add(new XElement("HorDE", NewMachineMeasurement.RMShorDE));
    machine.Add(new XElement("VertDE", NewMachineMeasurement.RMSvertDE));
    machine.Add(new XElement("AxDE", NewMachineMeasurement.RMSaxDE));
    machine.Add(new XElement("HorNDE", NewMachineMeasurement.RMShorNDE));
    machine.Add(new XElement("VertNDE", NewMachineMeasurement.RMSvertNDE));
    machine.Add(new XElement("AxNDE", NewMachineMeasurement.RMSaxNDE));
    */

    // ClientFile.Save(frmMain.ClientFileName);
}
```

So if I select machine 2 for example all info of the Companyprofile and other machines is lost and it store only the current information. Why is that so and how should I change it?

Comment: You save only the machine Element, Not the whole file (ClientFile)

Comment: You need to save doc, not machine.  See your earlier posting where I gave solution for the searching of the MachineProfile.

Comment: Ahhh yes yes I'm so sorry I'm trying to learn this stuff but I see I confused myself with certain names It is working now thanks for the patience and help!

Comment: The way you suggested works but unfortunately I can't connect it to the  public class "XmlRoot" Which I needed to use when I want to load the data later on. I altered to code above to show what I mean.